# Sorting a parsed XML file into cfg file

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am using this code to turn a XML file into a cfg file

```
import sys, lxml.etree

doc = lxml.etree.parse('settings.xml')

foo = open('settings.cfg', 'w')

for el in doc.findall('setting'):
    foo.write("%s=%s\n" % (el.attrib['id'], el.attrib['value']))
foo.close()
```

Is there a way to sort the tags before I write them to file and maybe ignore certain tags.

Input

```
<settings>
    <setting id="auto_backup" value="false" />
    <setting id="exitonbackspace" value="true" />
    <setting id="hidemousepointer" value="true" />
    <setting id="nb_backup_files" value="10" />
    <setting id="refreshonload" value="true" />
    <setting id="screen2" value="false" />
    <setting id="separator" value="" />
    <setting id="show_batch" value="true" />
    <setting id="show_log" value="true" />
</settings>
```

Current Output

```
auto_backup=false
exitonbackspace=true
hidemousepointer=true
nb_backup_files=10
refreshonload=true
screen2=false   
separator=
show_batch=true
show_log=true
```

Require Output

```
exitonbackspace=true
screen2=true
refreshonload=true
hidemousepointer=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary, `settings_dict`, for all the setting tags found in the xml.

Create a list, `settings_order`, for the order that you want the settings to appear in.

Iterate through  `settings_order`, if an element is present in `settings_dict` then you can output it.

```
import sys

try:
    from lxml import etree
except:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

doc = etree.parse('settings.xml')

settings_dict = dict([(el.attrib['id'], el) for el in doc.findall('setting')])
settings_order = ['exitonbackspace','screen2', 'refreshonload', 'hidemousepointer']

foo = open('settings.cfg', 'w')
for setting_id in settings_order:
    if setting_id in settings_dict:
        el = settings_dict[setting_id]
        foo.write("%s=%s\n" % (el.attrib['id'], el.attrib['value']))
foo.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Current Output
>
> Require Output

Uhmm...your input and current output appear to be sorted by id, and your 'require' output appears to be random.  So how would one sort your input to arrive at your require output?  Do we need to install the mindreader module?

If your input looked like this:

```
<settings>
    <setting id="hidemousepointer" value="true" />
    <setting id="show_batch" value="true" />
    <setting id="nb_backup_files" value="10" />
    <setting id="refreshonload" value="true" />
    <setting id="exitonbackspace" value="true" />
    <setting id="screen2" value="false" />
    <setting id="separator" value="" />
    <setting id="auto_backup" value="false" />
    <setting id="show_log" value="true" />
</settings>
```

You could sort by id like this:

```
import sys, lxml.etree

doc = lxml.etree.parse('settings.xml')

elements = doc.findall('setting');
sorted_elmts = sorted(elements, key=lambda elmt: elmt.attrib['id']);

for el in sorted_elmts:
    attribs = el.attrib
    print("%s=%s" % (attribs['id'], attribs['value']))

--output:--
auto_backup=false
exitonbackspace=true
hidemousepointer=true
nb_backup_files=10
refreshonload=true
screen2=false
separator=
show_batch=true
show_log=true
```